# Remove decimal separator with output format on real values in Fortran

Tags: formatting, fortran

I need to change output format of real (double precision) values in  an old Fortran program.

Currently, I have the following : `WRITE(*, '(a, F4.0)') "My floating value : ", 12886849674.89`

giving output `My floating value : 12886849675.`

I'd like to get rid of the ending ".", and show something looking like an integer rounding
`My floating value : 12886849675`

But since I have a huge bunch of files and variables I'd like to modify this way, I'd like to do so by changing only format, without casting my double variable. Is that even possible and how?

Comment: Why cant you round the value using `nint()` and print it as integer? The decimal point is an integral part of floating point output.

Comment: The linked question is much broader than this, but does consider removing digits after the decimal symbol and the decimal symbol itself (see one point of the answer). There could be some merit in having this much more focused question, but some motivation as to why "real but without decimal symbol" would be valuable.

Comment: @VladimirF, see my comment which was being written at the time. I can easily be persuaded it's not a good target/won't object if you reopen.

Comment: I don't want to do this, because that would mean addind nint() on hundreds of variables, and I'd rather not do that, when updating a few FORMAT instructions wouldnt be so much work. But I can understand that it is not a "normal" thing to do, as floating variables are supposed to have a decimal :)